# how to change selected row color of view based NSTableview in cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

i have tried many link from stake but not working .

see the below `image` i want change selected row color of `NStableview`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to subclass `NSTableRowView` and override its `drawSelectionInRect:` method.

Then you need to add `tableView:rowViewForRow:` to your tableViews delegate and return the subclass.

If you need further assistance, feel free to ask.

Comment: but what parameter can i pass in drawSelectionInRect: (NSrect:)

Comment: i know about this method and i have tried but i was not sure to pass what parameter in NSrect

Comment: drawSelectionInRect: should be called automatically, when you set up the tableView to include a horizontal line.